# Can two x-bit ALUs/FPUs be combined to create an equivalent a single 2x-bit ALU/FPU?

Tags: computers, alu

I was wondering, can 2 16-bit ALUs/FPUs be combined to create a 32-bit ALUs/FPUs, or are 4 ALUs/FPUs required? I was wondering if lower precision ALUs/FPUs can be combined in any way to create a higher precision equivalent ALU/FPU, so I may be understanding this topic completely wrong.

Comment: (2) 74181's (4-bit ALUs) can be combined to make (1) 8-bit ALU. You may be able to better understand your own question if you would just read the 74181 datasheet, read up on how to extend it, etc. It's all documented out there and it is NOT at all hard to understand. I don't know how old you are, but I figured it out easily at age 16. So it's not hard stuff. (The FPU question is a little more nuanced.)

Answer (score 1):

For integer add and subtract, and bitwise operations, yes. For more complicated operations no.

Comment: I've taken a look at a couple ALU diagrams, and I was wondering, would it be possible to take lower precision ALU components like adders/subtractors, multipliers, bit shifters, multiplexers and use more of each to create a higher precision ALU?